# andengine manage multiple collision

Tags: android, andengine

There is a better solution to manage multiple collisions than...

I've sprite X

Sprites of Group 1: Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4

Sprite of Group 2: sprites Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4

I've to ckeck when X collides at the same time with a sprite of group 1 and a sprite of group2.

now I've this sample code that works well..

```
if(X.collidesWith(Y1)&&X.collidesWith(Z1)||X.collidesWith(Z2)||
X.collidesWith(Z3)||X.collidesWith(Z4))
    {Y1 do something
    }
```

..and so on for Y2, Y3 and Y4

I was looking for something else, little shorter

Comment: You have to attach group1 sprite into single entity and group2 into other entity that work as a container. Then use sprite x to check collide with both container. This thing you have to check work or not.

Comment: If I group Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4 into an entity named Entity_Y and I check collision between X and Entity_Y, than is possible, on collision,  modify only the single sprite in Entity_Y (Y1, Y2, Y3 or Y4) that really collided with X?

Comment: That thing you have to check and reply back.

Comment: Y1, Y2, Y3 and Y4 are rectangular shapes. I grouped in entity group1. `if(X.collidesWith(group1)..` but I have following error The method collidesWith(IShape) in the type RectangularShape is not applicable for the arguments (Entity)

Comment: Then there is a no way to check manual each sprite collision. If you want then you can covert you code for box2d for better collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

If all sprites in your game have body and they are colliding with other body object then you can use Contact Listener in andengine

Contact Listener will automatically detect which two body objects are colliding and you can make some effects on collision